# where is the cache location of VMWare copy and paste cache on Mac?

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, vmware, cache

When copying and pasting between the host and virtual machine (VM), I have noticed a brief window that appears and disappears. It seems that this window may be responsible for temporarily storing the copied file somewhere within the system as a cache, before eventually moving or copying it to its final destination. I am interested in locating this cache location so that I can periodically clean it up.

To address this, I would like to inquire about the whereabouts of this cache location and how I can effectively remove its contents on a regular basis.

Comment: What is the Guest Machine?  Windows guests might respond to WinKey+V